# Magento 2: Product not showing in category page

Tags: magento2, product, category, category-products

I changed reindex mode `Update by Schedule` and add some product using custom script.

But now when I run reindex command (CLI) then none of the products are showing into category page. Product is visible perfectly in product page if I access them using product URL directly but not visible on category page.

Any idea please share with me. thanks.

Comment: check product inventory, it might be out of stock product.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the below options in your Magento Dashboard:

- reindex
- Magento cache
- Varnish cache